# Problems when binding The Viewmodel to the contextMenu of a control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently having a problem with my project where I pass the binding of the main viewmodel to the contextmenu.

opening the context menu (using the right mouse button obviously) for the first time gives me this error

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '(attached:DependencyObjectAttached.DataContextEx)' property not found on 'object' ''TextBlock' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=PlacementTarget.(attached:DependencyObjectAttached.DataContextEx).QuotationCommandProcessor.ConvertProductCommand; DataItem='ContextMenu' (Name=''); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

It may not be super big of a deal since the binding succeeds the second time the context menu opens, but as OCD as I was, I wish to fix this issue.

So here's what I have

- I have a Page, inside the page is a Datagrid, the Datagrid has a Column whose cell template is the PlacementTarget of the ContextMenu
- The context menu Command binds to a command of the view model of the page

The implementation i used was through attached property like this

```
<DataGrid ItemSource="{Binding MyItemSources}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyCellStyle}"/>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The style looks like this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyCellStyle">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" attached:DependencyObjectAttached.DataContextEx="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyPage}}}">
      <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
         <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <MenuItem Header="Click Here To Run Command" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.(attached:DependencyObjectAttached.DataContextEx).CommandFromTheViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
         </ContextMenu>
      <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
   </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

the DependencyObjectAttached.DataContextEx

> attached:DependencyObjectAttached.DataContextEx

is an attached property used to pass the viewmodel to the contextmenu

I have already tried using the Tag of the placementtarget (the Textblock) and it is working fine, however, I am using the Tag for some other purpose so attached property was the only option i can think of. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code, this achieves the datacontext access of your main window or Page in your case.

Trick is not to create a DataTemplate and instead create ContextMenu as resource directly and then use this context menu for your DataGridCell as shown below.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu1">
            <ContextMenu.Items>
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding DataContext.Title,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window} }"/>
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding DataContext.Title,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding DataContext.Title,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
            </ContextMenu.Items>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding VentingTypesCollection}">
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu1}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Please remember, DataContext.Title property is a simple string property from my viewmodel.

I think once you achieve access to datacontext, binding anything from viewmodel will be very straight forward.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: I don't know if this will work since contextmenus are not part of the visual tree. But i will still try

Comment: I think this should work, it work for me . If not do let me know what happens when you try this.

Comment: I've tried it, it did not work. I believe this was due to the fact that the contextmenu is inside a datatemplate.

Comment: Yes, Have you tried using without creating DataTemplate and just creating Context Menu as resource ?

Comment: That might work actually, placing the contextmenu inside of the page resource. let me try.

Comment: It's working now. I think this solved my problem. maybe you could add it to your main answer so i could accept it. thank you

Comment: Done added comment for the same.

Comment: Thanks man. Few more parts of my code can be transformed into this, making it a lot readable